# What does below parallel processing execution plan mean?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

I have a table tbl_a with 200 k records. I wrote a query to bring sum of id (int) column. Now execution plans shows 2 workers launched and below that parallel sequential scan on tbl_a is shown 3 times; with processing 66667 records each time(200k/3=66667). Now my question is since there were two workers so should there not be only two times table seq scan and each time with record 100k (200k/3). I am attaching the image which lists the table detail, query and query execution plan for better understanding.
[image]

Can someone tell me why with 2 workers there are 3 loops , each processing 6667 records out of total 200k records?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (the screen shot is barely readable) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Copy the text from the console then paste it into your question and put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two worker processes are additional to the session backend process, which is the “parallel leader”, so there are three processes working on the scan.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Laurenz Albe. it was very helpful. Laurenz I was doing streaming replication and was getting errors on pg_hba.conf. Could you please look and help on question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265853/postgresql-streaming-replication-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-use-from-host. It would really help.